# How to set property on an external element

Tags: css

From the image. How would you be able to apply a property to the label from the focus of the input?

I saw some examples but that only work if the label immediately after the input. Then it would be enough to use the + of the css .. but in this case it is one level outside the parent input.

this only works if the label is immediately after the input. It's not the case.

```
.container input:focus + label{
    font-size: 12px !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please **never** post images of code, always real code.

Comment: @connexo, pardon!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46406959/8620333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:focus-within` pseudo-class as well as the `~` selector.

```css
div.input:focus-within ~ label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<label for="">label</label>
```